# Finding instance id in NXLog config on EC2

Tags: windows, perl, logging, amazon-ec2

I have several ec2 instances running applications on windows. The logs have been requested to be persisted. To perform the coleacence and the auditing, Loggly was chosen.

For the windows instances, I have installed nxlog and configured it as suggested by Loggly. I want to replace the text `INSTANCEID` with the value returned by the url `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

I have not yet found a good example but the documentation says the configuration is PERL-like.

The example conf file

```
define ROOT C:\Program Files (x86)\nxlog
define CERTDIR %ROOT%\cert

define CUSTOMER_TOKEN 12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789012

Moduledir %ROOT%\modules
CacheDir %ROOT%\data
Pidfile %ROOT%\data\nxlog.pid
SpoolDir %ROOT%\data
LogFile %ROOT%\data\nxlog.log

<Extension json>
    Module      xm_json
</Extension>

<Extension syslog>
   Module xm_syslog
</Extension>

<Input internal>
   Module im_internal
   Exec  $Message = to_json(); 
</Input>

# Watch any file you'd like
<Input file_watch>
   Module   im_file
   File     "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nxlog\data\\nxlog.log"
   SavePos  TRUE
   Exec  $Message = $raw_event; 
</Input>

<Input eventlog>
    Module im_msvistalog
    Exec  $Message = to_json(); 
</Input>

<Output out>
   Module om_tcp
   Host logs-01.loggly.com
   Port 514
   Exec to_syslog_ietf();\
$raw_event = replace($raw_event, 'NXLOG@14506', '%CUSTOMER_TOKEN%@41058 tag="windows" tag="INSTANCEID"] [', 1);
</Output>

<Route 1>
   Path internal, file_watch, eventlog => out
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run a script prior to starting the nxlog service which replaces *INSTANCEID* in *nxlog.conf* with the value fetched from the url.
I guess INSTANCEID is fixed and doesn't change while the instance is up.